# How to refresh D3 tree, even though data has not changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have faced a problem with D3 tree - (only in Safari) when on top of one tree new one is opened in modal window and then closed all nodes become black (they are images originally).

As a workaround I have thought to completely redraw tree as soon as modal window  is closed. But I can not make D3 think that data (which is not actually changing) is new, I have tried to clone data object in order to make it exit() previous data. But it is not working it just draws the same nodes on top of existing ones.

**Update** - as was suggested in the comment - I have tried to reproduce the problem I have in a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KI8VR9Zl3KILPMSn2e5t?p=preview). Try to open modal window few times in Safari - initial tree pictures in nodes will become black.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $modal) {

});

app.directive('tree', tree);

function tree() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        replace: false,

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var treeData = [{
                "name": "Top Level",
                "parent": "null",
                "value": 10,
                "type": "black",
                "level": "red",
                "icon": "http://placekitten.com/g/48/48",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "Level 2: A",
                    "parent": "Top Level",
                    "value": 5,
                    "type": "grey",
                    "level": "red",
                    "icon": "http://placekitten.com/g/48/48",
                    "children": [{
                        "name": "Son of A",
                        "parent": "Level 2: A",
                        "value": 5,
                        "type": "steelblue",
                        "icon": "http://placekitten.com/g/48/48",
                        "level": "orange"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Daughter of A",
                        "parent": "Level 2: A",
                        "value": 18,
                        "type": "steelblue",
                        "icon": "http://placekitten.com/g/48/48",
                        "level": "red"
                    }]
                }, {
                    "name": "Level 2: B",
                    "parent": "Top Level",
                    "value": 10,
                    "type": "grey",
                    "icon": "http://placekitten.com/g/48/48",
                    "level": "green"
                }]
            }];

            // ************** Generate the tree diagram    *****************
            var margin = {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 120,
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 120
                },
                width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var i = 0;

            var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                .size([height, width]);

            var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                .projection(function (d) {
                    return [d.y, d.x];
                });

            var svg = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform",
                    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            root = treeData[0];

            update(root);

            function update(source) {

                // Compute the new tree layout.
                var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                    links = tree.links(nodes);

                // Normalize for fixed-depth.
                nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                    d.y = d.depth * 180;
                });

                // Declare the nodes…
                var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function (d) {
                        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                    });

                // Enter the nodes.
                var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                    });

                var defs = node.append('defs').attr('id', 'imgdefs');

                var roundedCircle = defs.append("pattern")
                    .attr("id", "grump_avatar")
                    // .append("svg:image")
                    // .attr("xlink:href", 'http://placekitten.com/g/48/48')
                    .attr("width", 48)
                    .attr("height", 48)
                // .attr("x", 0)
                // .attr("y", 0);

                roundedCircle.append("image")
                    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                        return d.icon;
                    })
                    // .attr("x", "-12px")
                    // .attr("y", "-12px")
                    .attr("width", "48px")
                    .attr("height", "48px");

                nodeEnter.append("circle")
                    .attr("cx", 48 / 2)
                    .attr("cy", (48 - 40) / 2)
                    .attr("r", 48 / 2)
                    .style('fill-opacity', 1)
                    .attr("fill", "url(#grump_avatar)");

                // Declare the links…
                var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                    .data(links, function (d) {
                        return d.target.id;
                    });

                // Enter the links.
                link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .style("stroke", function (d) {
                        return d.target.level;
                    })
                    .attr("d", diagonal);

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither your question nor your self-answer will provide anything to learn from unless you provide some more context and share some code. Have a look at [ask], [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic)and how to provide a [mcve]. Sticking to these rules will give you much more attention and readers able to understand your problem will much more likely be able to provide help.

Comment: @altocumulus  fair enough, I have added Plunker

Answer (score 0):

For now I've ended up with such solution - each time modal is opened I remove whole svg (`d3.select("svg").remove();`) element and then call another function to draw tree from the very beginning.